# calculating sum from another table using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table (District) have columns  (Id - District name) . And another table (delivery)  have columns (quantity - district Id). can i have a result like a table with every district name in a column and sum of quantity in other column using sql?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

**I understand that this question will be closed as this site is not about doing homework**

```
select a.district_name, b.total
from District as a
inner join
(
select district_id, sum(quantity) as total
from delivery
group by district_id
) as b
on a.id = b.district_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
SELECT dis.district_name,SUM(del.quantity) as quantity
FROM district as dis 
INNER JOIN delivery as del 
ON dis.id = del.district_id
GROUP BY del.district_id
```

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY`

Comment: in ansi sql you cannot use columns without aggregation function which are not in group by (simply - you cannot group by id and select name), this will work in non ansi compliant mysql which actually uses min as aggregation by default

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity      
FROM  
(  
   SELECT District.ID, District.Name, Delivery.Quantity  
   FROM District, Delivery  
   WHERE District.Id = Delivery.DistrictID  
) AS T1  
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

Comment: why do you need sub query here? if you're groupping by both columns - it is enough to have 1 query

Comment: you should also use `INNER JOIN` and not place join conditions in the where clause

Comment: @Used_By_Already most RDBMS understand this case and will treat both queries (with join or with cross join + filter in where) equally

Comment: @user3904057 not quite what I mean. This site asks that we use standards based code wherever possible, placing join conditions in the where clause is not to the latest ANSI standards for SQL. It would be a better answer if you used `INNER JOIN` etc.